# Upgraded to 19.10, boot up super slow

Tags: boot, 19.10

Just upgraded to 19.10, the boot up process is very slow and showing some error message like:

```
hdaudio hdaudioC0D2: Unable to bind the codec
```

After that, I can login and sound is OK. Anybody have similar issue and how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the "nomodeset" from the /etc/default/grub file as referred to other posts, just remember to do sudo update-grub before restart.

Comment: Please provide the other posts you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, i really can not find that link, but basically what i mentioned above is all that you need to do to solve the issue. That's what I have done. Now start very fast and won't go to black screen with more than one miniute...